# How to block removing rows on read-only DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Even why I can remove rows on read-only DataGridView?

I can set Enabled to false but then I can't even select and I don't really need this gray mask.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete what do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `AllowUserToDeleteRows` property to `false`

Answer (score 1):

you can handle event

```
private void dataGrid_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.ReadOnly) e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the answer the original question was asking for, but it was exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `ReadOnly` property only determines whether cells can be edited. It has no effect on the user's ability to remove rows. If you don't want to disable the control, you can effectively prevent row removal by setting the `RowHeadersVisible` property to false.

Edit: See @Dmitry's answer re: `AllowUserToDeleteRows`

Answer (score 0):

The best place to do this is on the ReadOnlyChanged event of your datagridview. And don't forget to disable adding new row too.

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView_ReadOnlyChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView.ReadOnlyChanged
    Me.MyDataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = Not Me.MyDataGridView.ReadOnly
    Me.MyDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = Not Me.MyDataGridView.ReadOnly
End Sub
```